# cut string after third occurence of <br> element with jquery

Tags: jquery, string, split

I got a string as follows:

```
<p class="remove">    
This should go:
<br>
this too
<br>
<br>
from here on I want it to stay
<br>
blabla
<br>
blabla
</p>
```

I want to cut the first part until the **third** occurence of **br** away with jquery.

I know that I can get it by the split function, but I can't get it to get the third br element as the selector.

Here is my code so far:

```
var replace = $('.remove').text();
alert(replace.split('br:nth-child(3)')[1]);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got it working now with the following code:

```
var replace = $('.remove').html().split('<br>').slice(3).join('<br>');
```

Only using split would cut the string after the next occurence of br again.

Answer (score 1):

You should use `.html()` instead of `.text()`, since you need to retain `<br>` tags. Also, split does not split on selection, it splits on string. So, you need to use `.split('<br>')` and rebuild your string from that array.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I got it working now with a slightly different approach. You can see it in my answer. And thanks for the hint with .html(), totally forgot to think about that.. :)